# JApplet: Non-static-method cannot be referenced in a static context error

Tags: java, netbeans, static, applet

People ask about this error a lot, but I've not been able to find an answer that helps me for the code I'm working on. I guess it is something to do with having an instance or something?

I want a user to be able to input a number in an GUI (GridJApplet) and on clicking "Go" have that number passed to a JPanel (GridPanel) to redraw a grid to that width and height.

I've tried creating a getter and setter in GridJApplet, but then cannot use the getter in my other class, it gives me the error "Non-static-method getGridSize() cannot be referenced in a static context". I'm working in NetBeans, and haven't finished this code yet. I really don't understand how to get the user input to work in another class.

Here is the code in GridJApplet

```
public void setGridSize() {
size = (int) Double.parseDouble(gridSize.getText());
    }

public int getGridSize() {
return this.size;
   }
```

This is the code from GridPanel

```
public void executeUserCommands(String command) {
    if (command.equals("reset")) {
        reset();
    } else if (command.equals("gridResize")) {
                NUMBER_ROWS = GridJApplet.getGridSize(); //error occurs here
            }

    repaint();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a static method; you need an instance of `GridJApplet` in order to call an instance method.

Or make it a static method.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the getGridSize() method on the GridJApplet class, not an instance of that class.  The getGridSize() method is not defined as a static method.  Therefore, you need to call it on the actual GridJApplet instance instead.

Answer (score 0):

Java 101:

Don't do this:

```
public void executeUserCommands(String command) {
    if (command.equals("reset")) {
        reset();
    } 
    else if (command.equals("gridResize")) {
                      // WRONG
        NUMBER_ROWS = GridJApplet.getGridSize(); //error occurs here
    }
```

Instead:

```
    else if (command.equals("gridResize")) {
        // You must specify an *instance* of your class (not the class name itself)
        NUMBER_ROWS = myGridJApplet.getGridSize();
    }
```